# Most elegant and efficient way to get a Map result from a JPA join

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

Lets say I have 3 entities:

`Car`
`Place`
`Visit`

A `Visit` represents the occurrence when a `Car` visited a `Place`, so it would have the time it arrived, the time it left, and 2 foreign keys, one to the `Car` and one to the `Place`.

In JPA, `Visit` has `@ManyToOne` relationship to `Car` and `@ManyToOne` relationship to `Place`. (So a `Car` can make many visits and a `Place` can have many visits), using the foreign keys above.

Lets say I wanted to know the list of (unique) `Car`s that visited all `Place`s (or a number of `Place`s, doesn't matter), what is the best approach to get a `Map<Place, List<Car>>` so that it is only done in one SQL query?

In normal native SQL we would just use `join` and `group by`, is there some JPA trick that can achieve this elegantly?

I am using JPA 2.0 (Hibernate 4.1).

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Guava (but you could easily do without):

```
String jpql = "select distinct place, car from Visit visit"
              + " inner join fetch visit.car car"
              + " inner join fetch visit.place place"

List<Object[]> placeAndCars = em.createQuery(jpql).getResultList();
ListMultimap<Place, Car> result = ArrayListMultimap.create();
for (Object[] row : placesAndCars) {
    result.put((Place) row[0], (Car) row[1]);
}
return result;
```